# How to save and load XTS objects using a loop?

Tags: r, xts

Assume that `symbols` is a character vector of stock symbols. After using `getSymbols` over the entire `symbols` vector I have them loaded in my workspace. To limit requests to Yahoo! servers I want to save these `xts zoo` objects in a files using the following code:

```
# Save to local drive
e = ".xts"
for (i in 1:length(symbols)){
  tempXTS = get(symbols[i]) # <= QUESTION relates to this line
  save(tempXTS, file = paste(dataFLD, Sys.Date(), symbols[i], e, sep = ""))
}
# Load from local drive
for (i in 1:length(symbols)){
  filepath = paste(getwd(), "/DATA/2013-12-21 ", symbols[i], ".xts", sep = "")
  load(filepath)
}
```

Question: I originally used `tempXTS` only for readibility of the code, but ran into issues when trying to load the objects from the `.xts` files. It seems the saving renames the object from say AAPL to tempXTS. The problem is, when I delete that line and substitute tempXTS wiht get(symbols[i]) in the next line I get this error (note dataFLD is the path to the data folder):

`Error in save(get(symbols[i]), file = paste(dataFLD, Sys.Date(), symbols[i],  : 
  object ‘get(symbols[i])’ not found`

Comment: Hi there, if symbols is a character vector, where is the time component or why is there a time component, to make this an xts or zoo object? And why do you want to subset each element before saving?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify. `symbols` is only an array of names. When you call e.g. getSymbols("AAPL") you get an xts/zoo object of the same name. I.e. the variable AAPL refers to the xts/zoo object. No subsetting. Trying to save each xts/zoo object separately. `save(AAPL)` would work for one symbol, but looping over a multiple symbols, as I do above produces the issue as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to assign `get(symbol[i])` to a temporary object, or to even use `get` in the first place.  As it says in `?save`, you can use `list=` to specify the name of an object to save.

```
e = ".xts"
for (sym in symbols){
  save(list = sym, file = paste0(dataFLD, Sys.Date(), sym, e))
}
```